# Recursive Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, recursion, business-intelligence

> I have a table called WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem.
>   Below is a screenshot of data found in WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem.
>   [WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39dlj.png)
>
> My requirement is to find missing node from WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem Table based on below condition.

1. Set all isMissing to 0
2. If child field has IcpUid field  NOT  NULL and 
   parent has IcpUid field  NULL 
   then set  child  parent  IsMissing to 1.
3. If child field has IcpUid field NULL and 
   parent has IcpUid field NULL  AND  parent  child  has IsMissing equal 1 
   then set  child  parent  IsMissing to 1.
4. Repeat step 3 until there is nothing more to update.

> I was able to meet step 1 to 3 in my SQL code but not step 4 as I need to do a for loop to check if there is no more update.
>   Below are my SQL code

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (
Code NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
Name NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
Level INT NULL,
IsMissing BIT NULL,
ParentCode NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
IcpUid NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
);

INSERT INTO @TEMP(
Code,
Name,
Level,
IsMissing ,
ParentCode ,
IcpUid 
)
SELECT 
Code,
Name,
Level,
IsMissing = 0,
ParentCode, 
IcpUid
FROM WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem 
WHERE IsDeleted = 0
;

UPDATE P SET IsMissing = 1
FROM @TEMP C
INNER JOIN @TEMP P ON P.Code = C.ParentCode
WHERE C.IcpUid IS NOT NULL 
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL
;
SELECT 
P.Code,
P.Name,
P.Level,
C.IsMissing ,
C.ParentCode ,
P.IcpUid 
FROM @TEMP P
INNER JOIN @TEMP C ON P.Code = C.ParentCode
WHERE C.IsMissing = 1
AND C.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL
ORDER BY LEVEL
```

> Can you please suggest an idea how I can build a recursive loop from above code.
>   Please note : there is a need to looping step 3, it might not be needed with current data but we are coding for all cases not just current data

Answer (score 0):

use `WHILE` or `CURSOR`. Example CURSOR:

`DECLARE @code VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 
Code
FROM WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem 
WHERE IsDeleted = 0`

`OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @code`

`WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN`

`UPDATE ...
INNER JOIN ... P ON P.Code = @code
WHERE C.IcpUid IS NOT NULL 
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL`

`FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name
END`
`CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor`

Answer (score 0):

> This is the code I was looking for.

```
DECLARE @TMP TABLE
(
Code varchar(40),
Name varchar(120),
level int,
ParentCode varchar(40),
IcpUid varchar(32),
IsMIssing bit
);
DECLARE @NumCount INT = 0;
INSERT INTO @TMP
SELECT
    Code,
    Name,
    level,
    ParentCode,
    IcpUid,
    IsMissing
FROM WarehouseStore.dws6.BeScheduleItem
WHERE isdeleted = 0
AND name not like '%DELETED%';
--Step 2
MERGE INTO @TMP TGT USING (
SELECT DISTINCT 
   P.Code,
   IsMissing = 1
FROM @TMP C
INNER JOIN @TMP P ON P.Code = C.ParentCode
WHERE C.IcpUid IS NOT NULL
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL
) SRC
ON TGT.Code = SRC.Code
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TGT.IsMissing = SRC.IsMissing;
--Step 3
SET @NumCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.Code)
FROM @TMP C
INNER JOIN @TMP P on P.Code = C.ParentCode
WHERE C.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND C.IsMIssing = 1
  AND C.IsMissing <> P.IsMissing);
WHILE (@NumCount > 0)
BEGIN
--loop
MERGE INTO @TMP TGT USING (
SELECT DISTINCT 
P.Code,
IsMissing = 1
FROM @TMP C
INNER JOIN @TMP P ON P.Code = C.ParentCode
WHERE C.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND C.IsMIssing = 1
AND C.IsMissing <> P.IsMissing
) SRC
ON TGT.Code = SRC.Code
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET TGT.IsMissing = SRC.IsMissing;
SET @NumCount = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT P.Code)
FROM @TMP C
INNER JOIN @TMP P on P.Code = C.ParentCode
WHERE C.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND P.IcpUid IS NULL 
AND C.IsMIssing = 1 
  AND C.IsMissing <> P.IsMissing );
END --end loop

SELECT *
FROM @TMP C
WHERE IsMissing = 1
ORDER BY Level;
```